# Python Tkinter Notebook positioning widgets using ".place"

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am not able to figure out why widgets are not visible when ".place" is used. It works when ".pack" is used. My GUI needs precision positioning of widgets and hence I need to use ".place". Am I doing anything wrong?

Environment: Python: 3.9.6 Windows 10 (21H1)

```
import tkinter as objTK
from tkinter import ttk as objTTK

root = objTK.Tk()
root.title("Tab Widget")
tabControl = objTTK.Notebook(root)
  
objSummaryTab = objTTK.Frame(tabControl)
objSettingsTab = objTTK.Frame(tabControl)
  
tabControl.add(objSummaryTab, text ='Summary')
tabControl.add(objSettingsTab, text ='Settings')
  
lb1 = objTTK.Label(objSummaryTab, text ="Summary")
lb1.place(x=5, y=5)  
          
lb2 = objTTK.Label(objSettingsTab, text ="Settings")
lb2.place(x=5, y=5) 

tabControl.place(x=5, y=5)

root.bind("<Escape>", lambda _: root.destroy())

root.geometry("500x500")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: _"My GUI needs precision positioning of widget"_ - why is that? Very, very few UIs have such a restriction.

Comment: My GUI contains tightly packed widgets. Even a slight misplace looks awkward. I tried .pack and .grid once and was not happy with it. Hence I stuck to .place. Maybe I haven't explored a lot about them as I am using python for few months now.

Comment: @SandeepSD: If you use `.pack()` or `.grid()` correctly, they should adjust so that the widgets fit in well with each other; that is, with no overlap. You can use the `tkinter.PanedWindow` to make various parts of the window resizable, so that if parts of widgets (like long labels) go out of view, they can still be accessed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is because `place()` does not automatically resize the widgets, like `pack()` and `grid()` do. You need to specify `width` and `height` arguments for `tabControl`: `tabControl = objTTK.Notebook(root, width=100, height=100)`, for example. In this case, `width` and `height` are in pixels.